# Inverse of element wise power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any identity related to "inverse of elementwise power of a matrix".

In other words, it is well known that $[A^{n}]^{-1} = [A^{-1}]^n$, can we say something about $[A^{.n}]^{-1}$ where $A^{.n}$ is all elements of $A$ raised to the power $n$.

Let us say $A$ is invertible, not a diagonal matrix, and $n\ne1$.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think so. Except for diagonal matrices.

Comment: You preserve the diagonal of triangular matrices if you commute $^{.n}$ and $^{-1}$.